# Profiling Java applications with DTrace on macOS

Tags: java, macos, profiler, dtrace

I am trying to profile a Java application using DTrace on macOS Sierra 10.12. I am using the JDK8:

```
⋊> ~ java -version
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)

⋊> ~ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home
```

My ultimate goal is to trace all Java method entries and exits for specific packages.

[DTrace Probes in HotSpot VM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/dtrace.html) and [Mac OS X Port Using HotSpot DTrace Probes](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/MacOSXPort/Mac+OS+X+Port+Using+HotSpot+DTrace+Probes) seem to suggest that this should in fact be supported on macOS. However, even when my Java application is running, there are no `hotspot` probes available and `jstack()` appears to fail:

```
⋊> ~ pgrep java
24564

⋊> ~ sudo dtrace  -ln 'hotspot*:::'
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

   ID   PROVIDER            MODULE                          FUNCTION NAME
dtrace: failed to match hotspot*:::: No probe matches description

⋊> ~ sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::read:entry /execname == "java"/ { jstack(); }'
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

dtrace: description 'syscall::read:entry ' matched 1 probe
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1 (ID 153: syscall::read:entry): invalid address (0xe2e3275e) in action #1
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1 (ID 153: syscall::read:entry): invalid address (0xe2e3275e) in action #1
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1 (ID 153: syscall::read:entry): invalid address (0xe2e3275e) in action #1
…
```

Providing the path to `libjvm.dylib` to the `dtrace` command does not seem to help:

```
⋊> ~ ll "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/server/"
total 31616
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel   1.4K Jun 22 15:02 Xusage.txt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    15K Jun 22 15:01 libjsig.dylib
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    15M Jun 22 15:02 libjvm.dylib

⋊> ~ sudo dtrace -L "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/server/" -ln 'hotspot*:::'
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

   ID   PROVIDER            MODULE                          FUNCTION NAME
dtrace: failed to match hotspot*:::: No probe matches description
```

So what am I missing?
How do I profile a Java application using the DTrace facilities?

Answer (score 7):

Well, I was too quick to discount the System Integrity Protection as a possible cause.

After executing `csrutil enable --without dtrace` in the Recovery OS (press ⌘R during boot) the `hotspot` probes now just show up:

```
⋊> ~ sudo dtrace -ln 'hotspot*:::' | wc -l
    1039
```